# Angular 2 Jasmine XHR error 404 not found when calling constructor

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular

I've been following the official tutorials to set up unit testing in Angular 2 using Jasmine. I want to mock a Profile object defined in another class. The web console displays an error when I try to instantiate Profile using its constructor; it states error loading file.

profile.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

export class Profile {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Unit-test.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Jasmine Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- #1. add the system.js and angular libraries -->
  <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script>
    // #2. Configure systemjs to use the .js extension
    //     for imports from the app folder
    System.config({
      packages: {
        'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
      }
    });

    // #3. Import the spec file explicitly
    Promise.all([
      System.import('profile.spec.js')
    ])
          // #4. wait for all imports to load ...
      //     then re-execute `window.onload` which
      //     triggers the Jasmine test-runner start
      //     or explain what went wrong
    .then(window.onload)
    .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

profile.spec.ts

```
import {Profile, ProfileService} from '../app/profile';

var guy: Profile = new Profile();

describe("Initialising Profile", function() {
    it("ID", function() {
        expect(guy.id).toBe(1);
    });

    it("Name", function() {
        expect(guy.name).toBe("Notguy");
    });
});
```

Web console error:

```
GET XHR http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/profile
    [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/profile
        Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/profile as "../app/profile" from http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/profile.spec.js
    Stack trace:
    error@http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1020:16
    bootstrap/</fetchTextFromURL/xhr.onreadystatechange@http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1028:13
```

The console does not complain when I don't call the constructor.

Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Simplified directory structure

```
root/
├── app
│   ├── boot.js
│   ├── boot.js.map
│   ├── boot.ts
│   ├── profile.js
│   ├── profile.js.map
│   ├── profile.ts
├── index.html
├── node_modules
├── npm-debug.log
├── package.json
├── test
│   ├── profile.spec.js
│   ├── profile.spec.js.map
│   ├── profile.spec.ts
│   └── unit-tests.html
└── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the SystemJS configuration as described below:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      'app': {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        format: 'register'
      },
      'test': {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        format: 'register'
      }
    }
  });

  Promise.all([
    System.import('test/profile.spec')
  ])
  .then(window.onload)
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting the error :(

Comment: Could you give us the structure of your project (folders and js / ts files in them)? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I think the problem is that you put the `unit-tests.html` file under the `test` folder. This should work if you move it in the same folder (root folder) than `index.html` and use the configuration I provided in my answer...

Comment: I think i've found the problem, it seems I wasn't importing the required angular 2 libraries. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes, `angular2-polyfills.js`, `system.src.js`, `bundles/Rx.js` and `angular2.dev.js` are required... You're welcome!